# How do I create a dummy variables using a byte format column in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata, dummy-variable

I have a gender column that says either "Female", "Male", or . for missing entry. I want to create a new column that gives dummy variable 1 if gender is female and 0 is gender is male (and continuing to give . for missing value). I tried to do `gen Fem = gender = "Female"` but this does not work and I get r(109) error.

I am assuming this is because the `gender` column is a byte format column.

Also, how do I interact dummy variable column with variables in a regression model on Stata?

Comment: sounds like your `gender` variable is already a dummy variable, but simply has value labels. (to see this compare `tab gender` with `tab gender, nolabel`).  You do not need to create a new variable.

Comment: True! Male is 1 and Female is 2. However, I want to use the dummy values to interact female with some other variables in the regression I am running. How can I do that with the current column?

Comment: In Stata we talk of variables, not columns. Also `byte` is a variable or storage type and not a (display) format.

Answer (score 2):

See `help fvvarlist`, and check out the information on the binary operator `#`

For a specific example, see below where I create a 100 row dataset with variables `y`, `x1`, `x2`, and `gender`, the last of which should be similar to yours (i.e. byte with Male and Female labels)

```
clear
set obs 100
set seed 123
gen byte gender = runiform()<0.3
recode gender 0=1 1=2
label define gender 1 "Male" 2 "Female"
label values gender gender
gen x1 = runiform()<0.7
gen x2 = runiform()<0.2
gen y = runiform()<0.5
```

I can include a interaction term using the `#` operator

```
regress y x1 x2 x1#gender
```

Comment: This may be a matter of taste, but I find the output of `regress y x2 x1##i.gender` more legible and the code easier to scan.